# When the new post which has no image published, save the specific image as the featured image ( by category )

Tags: images, save-post

As the title, I would like to save the post with the specific image as the featured image, when it is new published. Also I would like to save different images which is filtered by categories.

I have wrote the code below, it does not work as I wish to.

```
add_action('save_post', 'wp_force_featured_image', 20, 2);

function wp_force_featured_image($post_id, $post) {

    if( $post->post_type == 'post' && $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {
    
        if(!isset($_POST['_thumbnail_id'])) {       
            $categories = get_the_category( $post->slug );  
             if ( $categories = 'news' ) {      
              add_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', '3135' );
             }
             elseif  ($categories = 'bi' ) {
              add_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', '3138' );
             }
        }
        }
    }
```

I tried to get the category slug for comparing.

Any advises will help me a lot.

Thank you for your support in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional is in trouble.

`get_the_category()` returns an **object**, use foreach to find the specific category.

In addition, you assigned a value to the `$categories` variable, to compare you must use the [**comparison operators**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) ( Ex: == or === )

I refactored the code and adapted it to your case, I hope it helps.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wp_force_featured_image', 10, 3 );

function wp_force_featured_image( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if ( $update ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $post->post_type !== 'post' ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $post->post_status !== 'publish' ) {
        return;
    }

    $has_post_thumbnail = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );

    if ( ! empty( $has_post_thumbnail ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $categories = get_the_category( $post_id );

    $thumbnail_id = false;
    
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        if ( $category->slug === 'news' ) {
            $thumbnail_id = 3135;
            break;
        }

        if ( $category->slug === 'bi' ) {
            $thumbnail_id = 3138;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( $thumbnail_id ) {
      add_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $thumbnail_id, true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I shall test with your code!

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a custom theme and you just want to have some fallback images, an easier approach might be to do something like this in your template:

```php
<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
  the_post_thumbnail();
} else if (in_category('news') {
  echo wp_get_attachment_image('3135');
} else if (in_category('bi') {
  echo wp_get_attachment_image('3138');
}

?>
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, this may or may not be a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I am not sure why you wrote "echo", but has_post_thumbnail is something that I was missing. I shall look in more.

Comment: The function 'wp_get_attachment_image' only returns the image but doesn't print it, so you need 'echo'. :)